# Android Form Widget Size

Tags: android, themes, widget

How do I take into account form widgets eg Editbox, checkbox being different sizes in different android themes when designing my forms?

I am using proper relative layouts, but when I have several widgets in the table layout for example, and change the theme, some drop off the bottom!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the "dropping off the bottom", all you need to do is add a ScrollView.
If you don't know how to use it, you can look it up [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

If your aim is to *change* the sizes of your widgets based on the phone, all that you will need to do is give a different layout file for your activity for each ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi. with those specifications.
Look up "Providing different layout for different screen sizes" [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks, yes I have several hdpi xhdpi etc layouts, but as I understand it a user can give a phone a theme, and my app will use that to draw sightly different widgets (eg colour) but in the emulator, switching theme I can see that also the size is sometimes different - the Edit boxes are taller in "theme" than they are in "holo" for example, so I cannot fit as many on the screen (without scrolling)